# Play framework form template helpers do not take into account the actual arguments

Tags: playframework, argument-passing, form-helpers

When I pass arguments using the form template helpers, they do not take into account my arguments.
i.e. if I do some thing like for ex.: wanting to set, by default, the value of my input to "myValue", the input generated will not take as value "" (empty value) rather then "myValue" !!

And is the same for other arguments like 'size for ex.

```
@helper.inputText(myForm("username"), 'id -> "username", 'value -> "myValue")
```

Have you any idea ?

I'm using Play 2.1

Answer (score 0):

For the `id` field, try prefixing the fields with an underscore: `'_id -> "username"`

It's described [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers) in the docs, in the section titled Field Constructors.

...

With regards to the `value` field: if you wanted a default value for an object, wouldn't it be better to set that in the object constructor?

Or create an instance of the object with the default values and wrap that instance with the Form(T) to pass to your view?

That way if you changed the value of an object instance to anything but the default value, saved the object, and then rendered the form again to edit it, the object would show it's current value instead of `myValue`.

If what I've described is not what you want with regard to the `value` field, further down in the link above it also goes into creating custom field constructors that you could make with whatever logic you're looking for.